# Mysql - Finding a record that satisfies 2 exact dates

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, select

Fairly new to mysql & the stack overflow community. - I have a question that's been bugging me.

I'm trying to return the results of individuals that have taken out a book on 2 specific dates. This is my effort so far;

```
SELECT borrower.fname, borrower.lname
FROM borrower, loan
WHERE borrower.cardno = loan.cardno
AND loan.dateout = DATE '2019-01-01'
AND loan.dateout = DATE '2018-02-01';
```

I'm not sure why I'm not getting any results - When I run the query with just one date it comes up with results. I can see from these results that there are definitely records that should satisfy the criteria, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone pinpoint where I'm going wrong? I thought it looked quite straightforward but it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: How in the world should one date column have 2 different values at the same time? Did you mean `OR` ?

Comment: `AND (loan.dateout = DATE '2019-01-01'
OR loan.dateout = DATE '2018-02-01')`?

Comment: mysql or oracle? Please tag only the one database that you are using.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses `exists` twice:

```
select b.*
from borrower b
where
    exists (select 1 from loan l where l.cardno = b.cardno and l.dateout = date '2019-01-01')
    and exists (select 1 from loan l where l.cardno = b.cardno and l.dateout = date '2018-02-01')
```

With an index on `loan(cardno, dateout)`, this should be an efficient solution.

Alternatively, you can use aggregation:

```
select b.fname, b.lname
from borrower b
inner join loan l on l.cardno = b.cardno
where l.dateout in (date '2019-01-01', date '2018-02-01')
group by b.fname, b.lname
having
    max(case when l.dateout = date '2019-01-01' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when l.dateout = date '2018-02-01' then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: Hi GMB, thanks for your help. Completely forgot about this - Apologies for the late reply!